# Integer and character import from Excel to R

Tags: r, excel, import

I am trying to import a `.xls`-file that has the following structure:

praefix number ID

A 1 A01

A 2 A02

and so on. By exporting it to a .csv and running `read.csv2()` works fine. However, if I run `read.xls()` from gdata I messes up the ID-column. I understand these are stored as integer, rather than character. I could surely write a function [`paste(preafix, sprintf(number))`] to replace the column, but this is not the nice way to try. Any ideas?

Alternatively, I have tried to use `read.ods()`, however these packages will not install due to dependency issues. `read_excel()` has the same behavior as `read.xls()`.

Comment: Have you tried `read.xlsx` from the `xlsx` package?

Comment: I cannot install those automatically since `rJava is not available for package xlsxjars` and `rJava, xlsxjars are not available for package xlsx`.

Comment: Alright. Then may I suggest `read_excel` from the package `readxl`?

Comment: Alternatively, to attempt to answer your question: can you elaborate on how the ID-column is messed up?

Comment: Both `read_excel()` and `read.xls()` lead to the same result. They convert the ID-column to 0. `typeof[ID]` says `integer`.

Comment: I cannot recreate that problem. Perhaps the problem originates in your Excel sheet? What does `=ISTEXT(C2)` return? Here cell C2 is `A01` and should return `TRUE`. In fact, A2,A3, C2 and C3 should return `TRUE` while B2 and B3 should return `FALSE`.

Comment: Exactly like you wrote. `=ISTEXT(A#)` is `1`, `=ISTEXT(B#)` is `0` and `=ISTEXT(C#)` is again `1`. I guess it is not Excel, but R that is causing the trouble. More precisely, the import routine from `read.file`.